# Service name conflict in avahi when I update txt-record

Tags: ubuntu, avahi, homekit

I create one service file into avahi (/etc/avahi/services/test.service). I want to update txt-record into test.service. When I update service file using vi , I get an error Service name conflict. Avahi automatically start another service with # number like "Test" to  "Test #2".

```
Sep  1 09:02:57 imx28evk daemon.info avahi-daemon[412]: Files changed, reloading.
Sep  1 09:02:57 imx28evk daemon.info avahi-daemon[412]: Service group file /services/test.service changed, reloading.
Sep  1 09:02:57 imx28evk daemon.notice avahi-daemon[412]: Service name conflict for "Test" (/services/test.service), retrying with ".
Sep  1 09:02:59 imx28evk daemon.info avahi-daemon[412]: Service "Test #2" (/services/test.service) successfully established.
```

Comment: Please, put here contents of `/etc/avahi/services/test.service` file

Comment: I agree with @Oleg It will be difficult to diagnose the problem without knowing what test.service does

Comment: hi Aabglov and Oleg,
<service-group>
 <name replace-wildcards="yes">test</name>
 <service>
  <type>_hap._tcp</type>
  <port>2000</port>
  <txt-record>c#=91</txt-record>
  <txt-record>ff=0</txt-record>
  <txt-record>id=EC:A8:6B:FE:54:8F</txt-record>
  <txt-record>md=test</txt-record>
  <txt-record>pv=1.0</txt-record>
  <txt-record>s#=1</txt-record>
  <txt-record>ci=2</txt-record>
  <txt-record>sf=0</txt-record>
 </service>
</service-group>